# Child component won't update without a function property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I faced a really strange behavior with my React components, that I can't explain.

This is a minified version of my app:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prev) {
    if (!prev.isActive && this.props.isActive) {
      console.log('activated', this.props.title);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        className={this.props.isActive ? 'child active' : 'child'}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        {this.props.title}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const Child1 = reactRedux.connect((state, props) => ({
  isActive={props.isActive('Child1')}
  onClick={() => props.activate('Child1')}
  title="Child1"
}))(Child);

const Child2 = reactRedux.connect((state, props) => ({
  isActive={props.isActive('Child2')}
  onClick={() => props.activate('Child2')}
  title="Child2"
}))(Child);

class Root extends React.Component {
  state = { active: null };

  activate = (active) => {
    if (!this.isActive(active)) {
      this.setState({ active });
    }
  };

  isActive = active => this.state.active === active;

  renderChild = (ChildComponent, i) => (
    <ChildComponent
      activate={this.activate}
      isActive={this.isActive}
      key={i}
    />
  );

  render() {
    const children = [Child1, Child2];

    return (
      <reactRedux.Provider store={this.props.store}>
        <div>{children.map(this.renderChild)}</div>
      </reactRedux.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const reducer = (state, action) => ({});
const store = redux.createStore(reducer);
    
ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.6/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.7.2/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Ok, the problem is, that `componentDidUpdate` of the Child component didn't get called. However, if I pass a property containing a function to all my Child properties, it works like a charm.

```
renderChild = (ChildComponent, i) => (
  <ChildComponent
    activate={this.activate}
    isActive={this.isActive}
    key={i}
    asfafasg={() => {}}
  />
);
```

Is there anybody who knows where that behavior does come from? It is really strange. I already restarted my webpack builder etc, to be sure that this is not a weird caching problem.

When I click the spans, the state of the Root component will update correctly, however the componentDidUpdate method of the childs won't.

I have tested it without react-reduxs' connect function and it has worked to. So it seems to be a problem with the connect function.

Comment: did you meant to call `componentDidMount` instead of `componentDidUpdate`? by the way, where are you calling `activate`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call the activate method in this example. Updated my question. When I click the spans, the state of the Root component will update correctly, however the componentDidUpdate method of the childs won't.

Comment: Reupdated, the real code is correct, its just the minified example here, with this error. :/

Comment: It seems, that is a problem with react-redux. Child1 and Child2 are react-redux connected components. I will update my example.

Comment: try to include a running snippet :)

Comment: Ok, I will, thank you :)

Comment: Ok I found the solution. You could check my own answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution (and a reason). This behaviour comes from `react-redux` performance optimization. I have to tell react-redux to optimize it and it will work. This question is kind of related:

[React componentDidUpdate method won't fire on inherited props change if connected to a store that didn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623628/react-componentdidupdate-method-wont-fire-on-inherited-props-change-if-connecte)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me (beside the fact that you don't use `constructor` in your `class`)

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prev) {
    if (!prev.isActive && this.props.isActive) {
      console.log('activated', this.props.children);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span
        className={this.props.isActive ? 'child active' : 'child'}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const Child1 = props => (
  <Child
    isActive={props.isActive('Child1')}
    onClick={() => props.activate('Child1')}
  >
    Child1
  </Child>
);

const Child2 = props => (
  <Child
    isActive={props.isActive('Child2')}
    onClick={() => props.activate('Child2')}
  >
    Child2
  </Child>
);

class Root extends React.Component {
  state = { active: null };

  activate = (active) => {
    if (!this.isActive(active)) {
      this.setState({ active });
    }
  };

  isActive = active => this.state.active === active;

  renderChild = (ChildComponent, i) => (
    <ChildComponent
      activate={this.activate}
      isActive={this.isActive}
      key={i}
    />
  );

  render() {
    const children = [Child1, Child2];

    return <div>{children.map(this.renderChild)}</div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: He does not need a constructor, that's in his prototype chain and also use of static and member properties babel transform that allows him to do `state = {}` directly as well as binding of methods to instance via `=>`

Comment: i know he can do that syntax with babel transform, this is why i left his code untouched. i did mentioned it though as it's considered as a pattern in react to place your initial code in the constructor.

Comment: it's considered as a pattern in _OOP_ to place your [x]_code_ in the _method_ you wish to override/extend. he hasn't got any, though the middleware does it for him. as for code in constructor, you could also do stuff like `shouldComponentUpdate(...args){ return (localLogic) && super.shouldComponentUpdate(...args) }`.