# react doesn't get re-render after getting new store state into props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react and react-redux.
I used mapstatetoprops and mapdispatchtoprops to update view of my react component.
Except re-render doesn't work after redux store changed, everything works fine. Action dispatch works fine, reducer works fine, I can console.log store state and check difference.
At first, I used useDispatch and useSelector and everything worked fine. But I'm changing it to mapdispatchtoprops and mapstatetoprops to merge my code into my project teammate's code.

I tried to put this.props.(whatineed) directly in my render()'s return in component. As I understand, through mapstatetoprops, store state should be passed into my component's props.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { checked, notchecked } from '../../../actions';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import local from './address';
import './index.css';
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      localsel : state.selectedLocal.locals
    }
  }
let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        check: (btn) => dispatch(checked(btn)),
        uncheck: (btn) => dispatch(notchecked(btn))
    }
}
class Seoul extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        var btnclicked = (e) => {
            let btnname = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('id');
            if (e.target.checked) {
                console.log('checked');
                this.props.check(btnname);
            };
            if (!e.target.checked) {
                console.log('not checked');
                this.props.uncheck(btnname);
            };
            // HERE IS WHERE I CAN CHECK THE PASSED STORE STATE
            console.log(this.props.localsel);
            // -------------------------------------------------
        }
        return (
            <div className='localdiv localdiv1'>
                // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SEE MY STORE STATE
                {this.props.localsel.map(val=>{
                    return <h1>{val}</h1>
                })}
                // --------------------------------------------
                <ToggleButtonGroup className='togglebtngrp' type="checkbox">
                    <ToggleButton className='togglebtn0' onChange={btnclicked} variant="outline-secondary" value={0} id="entireseoul">Entire Seoul</ToggleButton>
                    {local.Seoul.map((value, index) => {
                        return (<ToggleButton key={index} className='togglebtn' onChange={btnclicked} variant="outline-primary" value={index + 1} id={value}>{value}</ToggleButton>)
                    })}
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Seoul);
```

this component is exported in parent component, which is

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Jumbotron } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Gyeongi, Incheon, Busan, Daegue, Daejeon, Sejong, Gwangju, Ulsan, Gangwon, Gyungnam, Gyungbuk, Jeonnam, Jeonbuk, Choongnam, Choongbuk, Jeju, Othercountry } from './Locals';
import Seoul from './Locals';
import './Detailsrch.css';

class Detailsrch extends Component{
    render(){
        var localselect = (e) => {
            let selector = document.getElementsByClassName('locals');
            let selector_local = document.getElementsByClassName('localdiv');
            let i = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < selector_local.length; j++) {
                selector_local[j].style.display = 'none';
            }
            let boxclass = e.target.getAttribute('name');
            if (boxclass) document.getElementsByClassName(boxclass)[0].style.display = 'block';
            while (selector[i]) {
                selector[i].className = 'locals';
                i++;
            }
            if (e.target.className == 'localtext') {
                e.target.parentElement.className = 'locals localclick';
            } else {
                e.target.className = 'locals localclick';
            }
        }
        return (
            <Jumbotron className='searchjumbo'>
                <p>Locals</p>
                <Seoul />
                <Gyeongi />
                <Incheon />
                <Busan />
                <Daegue />
                <Daejeon />
                <Sejong />
                <Gwangju />
                <Ulsan />
                <Gangwon />
                <Gyungnam />
                <Gyungbuk />
                <Jeonnam />
                <Jeonbuk />
                <Choongnam />
                <Choongbuk />
                <Jeju />
                <Othercountry />
                <hr className='firsthr' />
                <p>type</p><hr />

                <p>career</p><hr />

                <p>country</p><hr />

                <p>sex</p>
            </Jumbotron>
        );
    }
};

export default Detailsrch;
```

here's my reducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
const initialstate = {
    locals: []
}
const localSelector = (state = initialstate, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CHECKED':
            if(action.payload){
                var arr = state.locals;
                arr.push(action.payload);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    locals: arr
                };
            } else {
                return state;
            }
        case 'NOTCHECKED':
            if(action.payload){
                var arrnum = state.locals.indexOf(action.payload);
                var arr = state.locals;
                arr.splice(arrnum, 1);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    locals: arr
                };
            } else {
                return state;
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    selectedLocal: localSelector
});
export default rootReducer;
```

I expect when props value changes, component will re-render and I will see the change in the browser. Props value has changed, but nothing happens in browser.

Comment: Post your reducer also.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I add it at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mutating the redux state as below

```
var arr = state.locals;
arr.push(action.payload);
```

The redux state should be immutable. You can have a look at here for some tips on how to update the redux store in reducer.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: I watched the document, i dont really get it. Am I doing shallow copy of top level? Can you give me an example what should I use instead of `var arr = state.locals;` `arr.push(action.payload);` `return { ...state, locals: arr };`?? ;(

Comment: Sure, let me explain. Consider you have a state like this `{ locals: [] }`. If you    use your approach `var arr = state.locals; arr.push('something');` and now state becomes `{ locals: ['something'] }`. Now the state is mutated. When you mutate state the component may not be aware that state has changed.

You can use an immutable update pattern for example `const newLocals = state.locals.slice(); newLocals.push(action.payload); return { ...state, locals: newlocals }`

Comment: Thx so much! finally I get it. if I use `var arr = state.locals;`, then arr becomes reference variable of state.locals becuase they are arrays!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see `Detailsrch`  imported in `Seoul` but it's vice versa `Seoul` is imported in `Detailsrch` and as per the code and comments i can see `this.props.localsel` is changing and this is used in `Seoul` so render method of `Seoul` will be called and since there is no mapping or usage of `this.props.localsel` in `Detailsrch` so render method will not be called.

So if you want to re-render `Detailsrch` you need to change the mapping of `this.props.localsel` from `Seoul` to `Detailsrch` and pass this value as props to `Seoul` it should be working.
If still issue exists please post your code to sandbox/codepen/jsfiddle so that we can reproduce.

Comment: Yes, `Seoul` is imported in `Detailsrch`, I wrote it wrong. And I want to re render `Seoul` so I put {this.props.localsel.map(val=>{return <h1>{val}</h1>})} in return in render, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please can you put your code in jsfiddle/codepen somewhere so that we can reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are suffering from something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623628/react-componentdidupdate-method-wont-fire-on-inherited-props-change-if-connecte) post mentioned. One trick to make your component to get the changes from the store (When passing state value from the store as a prop) is to make a deep clone of your props (Or the prop in which you want to get the change), for this you could use JSON:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(propToClone));
```

Hope this helps.

P.S.: Don't clone props that are functions, because JSON will erase/ignore them.